# Unable to Add Controller

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, asp.net-mvc-4

I am new to MVC web application development.
I am trying to add a controller after adding my model and DbContext class.

But when i am trying to this controller using Entity framework it gives me an error of

```
Unable to cast object of type 'System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.ObjectContext' to 'System.Data.Objects.ObjectContext'
```

I am using `EF-6.1.1` (latest update)

Following are my Model and Context Class..

```
 public class EmpDetails
    {
        [Key]
        public int Id { get; set; }

        public string EmpId { get; set; }


        public string EmployeeName { get; set; }
    }


 public class ModelContext : DbContext
    {
        public DbSet<EmpDetails> Employee { get; set; }
    }
```

When i am trying to add a controller I get following error.

[image]

Please suggest some solution to this problem. what is going wrong with it..

here is the process through which i am adding Controller

[image]

[image]

Comment: how are you trying to add the controller?

Comment: @ArijitMukherjee:  I have updated my post with 2 images.. please take a look..

Comment: it is not supported ASP.NET MVC 4 scaffolding does not support Entity Framework 6 or later

Comment: I think this is because of the Model binding due to DBContext and ObjectContext

Comment: Can you please suggest .. what to do next to correct it..

Comment: ignore the scfolling

The error message is self explanatory

Comment: try changing
`DBContext` to `ObjectContext`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/56419/discussion-between-mahima-gandhe-and-arijit-mukherjee).

Answer (score 1):

Entity Framework brought [breaking changes](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/upgradeef6.aspx) between versions 5 and 6. In order for it to go completely open source, they moved all of the libraries out of band and they are now all completely within the EntityFramework assembly in NuGet. A side effect of this was that many of the namespaces for Entity Framework has changed:

> The namespaces for DbContext and Code First types have not changed.
>   This means for many applications that use EF 4.1 or later you will not
>   need to change anything.
>
> Types like ObjectContext that were previously in
>   System.Data.Entity.dll have been moved to new namespaces. This means
>   you may need to update your using or Import directives to build
>   against EF6.
>
> The general rule for namespace changes is that any type in
>   System.Data.* is moved to System.Data.Entity.Core.*. In other words,
>   just insert Entity.Core. after System.Data. For example:
>
> System.Data.EntityException => System.Data.Entity.Core.EntityException
>   System.Data.Objects.ObjectContext =>
>   System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.ObjectContext
>   System.Data.Objects.DataClasses.RelationshipManager =>
>   System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.DataClasses.RelationshipManager

The reason you are seeing the error is that you are using a previous version of MVC, which was targeting an earlier version of Entity Framework. The scaffolding is going to be assuming the old namespaces.

You can try upgrading to the newest version of MVC and your scaffolding will work again. Either that or downgrade EF6 (I don't recommend this, it has a lot of really great features). The third option is to manually fix your scaffolded code every time.

Answer (score 0):

While using ASP.Net MVC 3/4, Entity framework assembly (.dll) would be automatically referenced with a lower version (5.0.0.0). And when you update this to a higher version an explicit type conversion is required for which you are getting this error. one way to fix this problem is, **use the existing version of Entity Framework (5.0.0.0) without updating to higher version**.